# Redim Preserve multidimensional array

Tags: arrays

I have a SQL test database, which has Email, Password and Name columns (please see image below). I am trying to store them in multidimensional array through ASP classic.

[image: Test database]

I need to redim preserve my array however, I am not able to do it right. right now, for testing purposes, I have 8 rows in my SQL test database so my redim has 8 comma i: `ReDim Preserve myDATA(8,i)`

Hard coding 8 is not going to work, we are going to have whole a lot more rows to work with, I am not sure how to increment it.

```
dbopen
set dataRS=server.createobject("ADODB.recordset")
set dataRS=conn.execute("select email,password,firstname,lastname from Test.dbo.Users")

i=0

dim myDATA()
while not dataRS.EOF

ReDim Preserve myDATA(8,i)

myDATA(0,i) = dataRS("email")

myDATA(1,i) = dataRS("password")

myDATA(2,i) = dataRS("firstname")

i=i+1

dataRS.MoveNext
wend
```

Comment: Add tag for the coding language you are using

Comment: Also edit and add a tag for which type of SQL server.